# Finding amount of energy transfer for $^4He$ and $\gamma$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, nuclear-physics, conservation-laws

I'm doing practice questions for an upcoming exam and I became stuck on this one (found on OpenStax [here](https://openstax.org/books/university-physics-volume-3/pages/10-challenge-problems#fs-id1170902649792)):

> For the reaction, $n+^3He→^4He+\gamma$, find the amount of energy transfers to $^4He$ and $\gamma $(on the right side of the equation). Assume the reactants are initially at rest. (Hint: Use conservation of momentum principle.)

What I've done so far:
Using Conservation of Energy:
$\sum$ rest mass energies of incident particles (reactants) $=$ moving energy of $^4He$ $+$ energy of photon

So, $m_nc^2+m_{^3He}c^2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}m_{^4He}c^2+E_\gamma$

Subbing in mass values and rearranging gives

$0.667=\frac{c+v}{c\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$

I have no idea where to go from here, I don't know how to get rid of the Lorentz Factor, or how to incorporate Conservation of Momentum.

Answers are $E_{\gamma}=20.6$ MeV & $E_{^4He}=5.68\times 10^{-2}$ MeV, no working solutions are provided

Comment: In relativistic kinematics (billiards - type questions), of which this is one, the Lorentz transformations are usually not relevant and writing out $1/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ generally takes you in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things that may help

1.it maybe easier to leave you energy equation in terms of the energy of the gamma ray and helium nucleus.

2.There is a useful relationship between the energy of a photon ($E=h\nu$), and its momentum ($p=\frac{h}{\lambda}$), that can be derived using the relation $c=\nu\lambda$.

3.There is also a [general relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_relation) between the energy and the momentum of a 'particle',
$$(cp)^2=E^2-(m_0c^2)^2$$
that holds for any speed, with $m_0$ being the rest mass.

Now as the reactants started from rest, implies that
$$p_\gamma=p_{^4He}$$
$$cp_\gamma=cp_{^4He}$$
$$(cp_\gamma)^2=(c p_{^4He})^2$$

Now if you combined this with the expressions from points 2 & 3. You get another expression for the energy of the $^4He$ and the $\gamma$ ray.

Then you combined this expression with the expression you have and then solve, using your favourite simultaneous equations technique, for the energies

Hopefully that helps

Comment: $v$ is frequency right? I usually use a different notation for it

Comment: Sorry, yes it is, I forgot there might be different notation.